# A Lynchian '90s Film About Small 1950s Midwestern Town With Kidnapping, Rape, Murder, And Suicide?

Tags: identify-this-movie

*I do not mean it was a David Lynch film. It is not Blue Velvet. It is "Lynchian."*

Likely made in the early 1990s. American film, color, well made. Category: drama. Very creepy, slow, and Lynchian.

Based in a small Midwestern town in the 1950s, perhaps Kansas or Oklahoma, post-Dust Bowl.

I can't remember a plot, but I think it was based around one family with an older son who is wanting to leave his hometown but feels bad about leaving his mother (this is just a guess, as my memory is foggy).

WHAT I DO REMEMBER:

There is a group of hoodlums (they look like '50s teenagers with white T-shirts, jeans, and slicked-back hair) who drive around town in a black(?) car, staring at the other townfolk, making them nervous. At one point, they get a young (teenage?) girl to get in the car with them. She is never seen again.

A man (probably the girl's father?) (also, I believe he worked at the town's only gas station) pours gas on himself and lights himself on fire (as the main kid watches... maybe it was his dad... darn, I have a foggy memory).

To sum it up: Very creepy, Lynchian, Midwestern, 1950s, hoodlums in a car kidnap a girl and kill her, man pours gasoline on himself and sets himself ablaze. Lynchian, very.

Comment: I wish you luck. Anyway- congrats on the most parentheses I've seen on a first-timer's post in a while. 14 if I'm not mistaken. Maybe try to clarify a bit more before you post. I'll be interested in seeing what the answer is, if you get one, as I'm a Lynch fan.

Comment: @MeatTrademark Still way better and clearer than most identify questions.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I agree there. No downvote from me. "Very creepy, Lynchian" is enough for me to be interested. I just wish knew the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it, only took me 15+ years of searching. It's [The Reflecting Skin](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100469/):

> A young boy tries to cope with rural life circa 1950s and his
>   fantasies become a way to interpret events. After his father tells him
>   stories of vampires, he becomes convinced that the widow up the road
>   is a vampire, and tries to find ways of discouraging his brother from
>   seeing her. He must deal with an abusive mother, a father with a
>   charge of molestation, a band of youths creating havoc, and an
>   unforgiving environment in general.

By the way, I discovered it using [this site](http://www.jinni.com/movies/the-reflecting-skin/)'s ingenious search.

Comment: Looks terrifying.